# Using Drop-down Boxes to Select Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hoping you can help!

I'm trying to build an extremely basic character builder which allows people to choose the head, body and feet using `drop-down` boxes. Three `drop-down` boxes will correspond to the three segments, allowing the person to choose the body parts.

Using code I've found online, I've managed to build what I need but I can only get one segment working.

Here's my current code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Character Selector</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <style>
        .details_div {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #details_book {}
        
        #details_movie {}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDiv() {
            // hide any showing
            $(".details_div").each(function() {
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
            });

            // our target
            var target = "#details_" + $("#test_select").val();

            // does it exist?
            if ($(target).length > 0) {
                // show it
                $(target).css('display', 'block');
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // bind it
            $("#test_select").change(function() {
                showDiv();
            });

            // run it automagically
            showDiv();
        });
    </script>

    <div id="head">
        <div id="details_head_tchoukball" class="details_div">Tchoukball Head</div>
        <div id="details_head_surfer" class="details_div">Surfer Head</div>
        <div id="details_head_photo" class="details_div">Photo Head</div>
    </div>

    <div id="selectors">
        <select id="test_select">
            <option value="">- Select Head - </option>
            <option value="head_tchoukball" selected="selected">Tchoukball</option>
            <option value="head_surfer">Surfer</option>
            <option value="head_photo">Photo</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Each div (depending on the segment) will eventually have an image in which corresponds to what is currently text.

Can anyone advise me where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: its working already, onchange select all according to selected option required div is being displayed. even it is working in your attached demo too

Comment: update your question with the code that does not work.. because this one "works"

Comment: Thanks Farhan and @elio.d - I will when I'm back at my machine. If I haven't been clear enough, I basically need three of what I've created to work independently in one document.

Comment: I figured it out! I was making silly syntax errors when I tried to make more than one. Thanks